# How to filter last entries with JSP c:forEach and c:if?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm trying to develop a Spring MVC application with JSP pages and I've run into a problem. It's more of a creativity problem than a code problem, but here goes:

So the application basically recieves a recipe (fields Name, Problem Description, Problem Solution, etc) and slaps an ID on it as it is created.

What I want is to show on the front page the **last** 3 recipes created. I've come up with a code that apparently shows the **first** 3 recipes created:

```
<c:forEach var="recipe" items='${recipes}'>
    <c:if test="${recipe.id < 4}
        <div class="span4">
            <h3<c:out value="${recipe.inputDescProb}"></c:out></h3>
            <p><c:out value="${recipe.inputDescSol}"></c:out></p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">Details &raquo</a></p>
        </div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Any ideas on how to show the **last** 3 recipes created instead?

Comment: Are you doing this because you're retrieving the list of receipes (one more time) using ajax or something similar?

Comment: Nope, not using ajax. For now its only local through a local map, no persistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `fn:length()` EL function to calculate the total number of recipes. Before we use any `EL function` we need to import the necessary `tag library` as well.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Then we use `<c:set>` to set the total as a page-scoped attribute.

```
<c:set var="totalRecipes" value="${fn:length(recipes)}" />
```

`<c:forEach>` allows you to get a loop counter using its `varStatus` attribute. The counter's scope is local to the loop and it increments automatically for you. This `loop counter` starts counting from 1.

```
<c:forEach var="recipe" items='${recipes}' varStatus="recipeCounter">
  <c:if test="${recipeCounter.count > (totalRecipes - 3)}">
    <div class="span4">
      <h3<c:out value="${recipe.inputDescProb}"></c:out></h3>
      <p><c:out value="${recipe.inputDescSol}"></c:out></p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">Details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

**EDIT**: Use the `count` property of `LoopTagStatus` class to access the current value of the iteration counter in your EL as `${varStatusVar.count}`.

Comment: Nice explanation, I'm only touching base on these JSTL methods and I got it how it all works. I'm still getting an error though. When i load up the page with no entries, it loads fine. But when I input 1 or more recipes and go back to the homepage, i get this: `Cannot convert javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@ffed1d of type class javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status to class java.lang.Long` I'm guessing the problem is on the For Loop ?

Comment: Use the `count` property and put parenthesis in ${recipeCounter.count > (totalRecipes - 3)} to avoid operator precedence side effects.

Answer (score 8):

No need to check length, just use the `.last` property of the `varStatus` variable.

```
<c:forEach var="recipe" items="${recipes}" varStatus="status">
  <c:if test="${not status.last}">
    Last Item
  </c:if>
<c:forEach>
```

Side note, you can also get the `.first` and `.count`

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the current count against the total collection size using `${fn:length(recipes)}`:

```
<c:set var="total" value="${fn:length(recipes)}"/>


<c:forEach var="recipe" items='${recipes}' varStatus="status">
  <c:if test="${status.count > total - 3}">
    <div class="span4">
      <h3<c:out value="${recipe.inputDescProb}"></c:out></h3>
      <p><c:out value="${recipe.inputDescSol}"></c:out></p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="/recipes/${recipe.id}">Details &raquo</a></p>
    </div>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

*Edit:*

You will need to import `fn` first to make the JSTL `fn` available for use:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Comment: I tried that and I get `/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp(31,30) PWC6287: The attribute prefix fn does not correspond to any imported tag library` Line 30: `<div class="row">` (thats okay) and Line 31: `<c:set var="total" value="${fn:length(recipes)}" varStatus="count"/>` anything I got to import for this to work ?

Comment: `varStatus` attribute has been used incorrectly. It should be used inside `c:forEach>`. Refer to my answer for details.

Comment: Okay, I imported JSTL functions, but still, I get `PWC6131: Attribute varStatus invalid for tag set according to TLD` which refers to `<c:set var="total" value="${fn:length(recipes)}" varStatus="count"/>` (Comment above I think sums it up - what would be the correct usage, if I may?)